# What does the XML parser complains the presence of header and timestamp in my XML document?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I tried xml parser in Python and an online parser from http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp.

I am getting "not well-formmated" error on line 5. Full source is here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=nwieVSv4

If you remove `<Head>...</Head>` or put that section inside `<Entries>` the complain will go away.

What's wrong with my XML document? Why does the parser dislike my header section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because an `xml` document can only have one root node. Yours have two, `<head>` and `<entries>`